# SFTP read-only access to another directory

Tags: symbolic-link, sftp, chroot

### **My Goal:**

I have sftp user **sftp1** which has chrootdir to `/sftp/sftp1`.
I want to add read-only access via sftp to user **sftp1** on directory which is `/home/user2/some/path/to/directory`

### **Expected result:**

User **sftp1** connect using sftp client and sees both directories `/sftp/sftp1` and `/home/user2/some/path/to/directory` (and of corse can download files from those directories)

User2 must be able to do everything - read, wirte, delete in his `/home/user2`

### **Question**:

How can I make user **sftp1** read both directories and still allow **User2** to keep their access untouched?

Comment: Please ask a clear precise question.

Comment: Im pretty new to ubuntu (and linux) I have no idea what could not be clear here...